# Client review js overlay

Tags: javascript, overlay, acceptance

When your construction inspector walks through a building they drop blue tape over all the nails that are hanging out of the wall and paint that's not done right. How do we do this with client acceptance of websites? Is there a tool like crazyegg that overlays your website and allows clients to annotate and mark bits that are out of whack? Failing that, how do you cope with the incredible amount of feedback that clients usually generate?

Thanks,
Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Pat. I think the actual app I was looking for is Notable which basically does what you were suggesting but does it in a fairly sveldt fashion. [Notable](http://notableapp.com)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a tool that does it for you, but my approach when a client wants this is to create a PDF of screenshots that the client can annotate with comments.